# How to wrap the main text around long figure and caption?

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

I am quite new to Latex and have a very simple formatting problem.

I have a very long figure that I would like to span the entire page and have the caption on the side. As the caption is much smaller than the figure, I would like to wrap the main text around the figure and caption, as illustrated below. I tried multiple approaches with wrapfigure, minipage, SCfigure, but I can't seem to get it working. Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us, what you try so far? Pease ...

Answer (score 1):

This uses `paracol`, plus `\splitpar` and `\continuepar` to simplify paragraph breaking.

BTW, you don\t have to make the columns the same width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter*
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\newsavebox{\textbox}
\newcommand{\splitpar}[2][\textwidth]{% #1 = width of column (optional), #2 = rest of paragraph after split
  \unskip\strut{\parfillskip=0pt\parskip=0pt\par}%
  \global\setbox\textbox=\vbox{\hsize=#1\relax\noindent\strut #2\strut}}
\newcommand{\continuepar}{\unvbox\textbox}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

Suspendisse vel felis. Ut lorem lorem, interdum eu, tincidunt sit amet, 
lao-\splitpar[\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep]{reet \sloppy
vitae, arcu. Aenean faucibus pede eu ante. Praesent enim elit, rutrum at,
molestie non, nonummy vel, nisl. Ut lectus eros, malesuada sit amet, fermentum
eu, sodales cursus, magna. Donec eu purus. Quisque vehicula, urna sed ultricies
auctor, pede lorem egestas dui, et convallis elit erat sed nulla. Donec luctus.
Curabitur et nunc. Aliquam dolor odio, commodo pretium, ultricies non, pharetra
in, velit. Integer arcu est, nonummy in, fermentum faucibus, egestas vel,
odio.}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\noindent
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth, height=\textheight]{example-image}
\switchcolumn

\begin{figure}
\abovecaptionskip=0pt
\caption{\lipsum[2]}
\end{figure}

\sloppy% SOP for anrrow columns or bad hypehnation
\continuepar

\lipsum[6]

Sed commodo posuere pede. Mau-\splitpar{ris \fussy
ut est. Ut quis purus. Sed ac odio.
Sed vehicula hendrerit sem. Duis non
odio. Morbi ut dui. Sed accumsan risus
eget odio. In hac habitasse platea
dictumst. Pellentesque non elit. Fusce
sed justo eu urna porta tincidunt.
Mauris felis odio, sollicitudin sed, volutpat
a, ornare ac, erat. Morbi quis
dolor. Donec pellentesque, erat ac sagittis
semper, nunc dui lobortis purus,
quis congue purus metus ultricies tellus.
Proin et quam. Class aptent taciti
sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Praesent
sapien turpis, fermentum vel, eleifend
faucibus, vehicula eu, lacus.}

\end{paracol}

\continuepar

\lipsum[8]
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]