# Turn off two columns only on new page

Tags: tcolorbox, page-breaking, two-column, paracol

I know that `paracol` allows me two typeset two separate texts in separate columns. However, I want the two-column layout to terminate only at the page break after the first column text runs out [[1]](https://journals.upd.edu.ph/index.php/phr/article/view/8945/7893).

```
+-----------------+
| Header          |
+------+----------+
|      |          |
| Side |  Main    |
| Text |  Text    |
|      |          |
|      |          |
|      |          |
|(fill)|          |
+------+----------+
   ~ pagebreak ~ 
+-----------------+
|                 |
|    Main Text    |
|    Continued    |
|                 |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

How can I achieve this? Non-column solutions using `wrapfig` (e.g., with `tcolorbox`) does not work as the main text will start with a section heading.

Comment: you can't change the text width at an automatic page break as page breaking happens after the paragraphs have been broken into lines based on the column width. so you will need a forced page break and `\onecolumn`

Comment: See `\splitpar` and `\continuepar` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652958/how-to-wrap-the-main-text-around-long-figure-and-caption/652995?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C16.7242#652995  You can see where to split it in a longer trial run.